# Enabling a minor mode with a file-local variable prop line

Tags: file-local-variables, minor-mode

The first line of a plain-text file reads:

```
# -*- eval: (auto-revert-tail-mode 1); -*-
```

Yet Emacs does not enable `auto-revert-tail-mode` after opening this file.  What is wrong?

Comment: It works here, so your syntax is correct. Does it do that with only one file, or all? Only plain-text files, or also files with other major modes? What is the major mode? (`text-mode`, `fundamental-mode`, other?)

Comment: Right.  I forgot to try with `emacs -Q`, too; and it works there.  My Emacs configuration must be messed up: there are many that don't work, besides this one.

Comment: Any chance you've changed the value of `enable-local-variables` or `enable-local-eval`?

Comment: @glucas: `custom-set-variables` was setting `enable-local-eval` to `nil`. I don't remember having set this option myself. I suppose that Customize did it when I was trying to stop Emacs from pestering me about whether to apply file-local variables or not. I will leave this variable as `nil`, though, and I will find another way to enable `auto-revert-tail-mode` on this file.  If you convert your comment to an answer, I will select it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the variables `enable-local-eval` and `enable-local-variables`. If you've changed one or both of these from their default values it could explain the behavior you are seeing.

For example if `enable-local-eval` is nil then that eval line in your file would be ignored.